# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined, webpack error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, module

I'm using node modules for a client application in the browser. I get 
'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined' when I try to require a constructor function from a neighbouring file into the app.js. app.js and Desktop.js are located in the same folder so the relative link path should be correct.

**app.js**

```
console.log('hello')
const Desktop = require('./Desktop')
let newVar = new Desktop()
console.log(newVar.height)
```

**Desktop.js**

```
function Desktop () {
  this.height = 3
}

module.exports = Desktop
```

webpack is also installed with the following config settings:

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'build.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    watchContentBase: true,
    port: 4000,
    public: 'localhost:4000'
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // set up standard-loader as a preloader
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'standard-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        options: {
          // Emit errors instead of warnings (default = false)
          error: false,
          // enable snazzy output (default = true)
          snazzy: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: do you have express installed? i think that allows require to be used

Comment: I don't think so, normally it works with webpack. I'm building an application for school so have to use the tools provided.

Comment: webpack however uses commonjs